# transform opencover xml output to ncover xml

Tags: jenkins, hudson, ncover, opencover

I need the ability to import opencover coverage results in to Jenkins to pull coverage trending data over time. 
It appears that the best way to do this is going to be finding a way to convert the opencover xml format to ncover format, and then use the NCover plugin to import the results. Is there an existing xslt that will transform opencover to ncover, or an open source tool that will do the conversion?
I've searched, and I'm finding nothing.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following XSLT is available on the [OpenCover wiki](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/wiki/Monitoring-coverage-in-Atlassian-Bamboo) which might get you started.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" standalone="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/CoverageSession/Modules">
    <coverage>
      <xsl:for-each select="Module[not(@skippedDueTo)]">
        <module name="{ModuleName}">
          <xsl:for-each select="Classes/Class">
            <xsl:if test="count(Methods/Method) &gt; 0">
              <class name="{FullName}">
                <xsl:variable name="className" select="FullName" />  
                <xsl:for-each select="Methods/Method">
                  <method class="{$className}">
                    <xsl:for-each select="SequencePoints/SequencePoint">
                      <seqpnt visitcount="{@vc}" />
                    </xsl:for-each>
                  </method>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </class>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </module>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </coverage>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: very cool. That should get me close, if not completely there.