# Jenkins - NUnit/MSTest Code Coverage Graph

Tags: c#, jenkins, nunit, code-coverage, opencover

Is it possible to produce a graph of code coverage v time in Jenkins for NUnit/MSTest?

I can produce a code coverage report with OpenCover and ReportGenerator.  I would prefer to be able to visualise this with a graph.  The [NUnit plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NUnit+Plugin) only produces of a graph of tests run or test failures over time.

On a separate note, does anyone know how to get OpenCover to set the %ERRORLEVEL% batch variable is a test fails during code coverage calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Jenkins Plot plugin - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin

I did it in long time ago. I was putting on graph data from IIS logs queried with logparser.

Answer (score 1):

I created this [nodejs application](https://github.com/sawilde/metrics-store) with the [google charts output](http://opencover-metrics.herokuapp.com/charts/sample_chart.htm) (but it may be overkill for your needs)

In the end just extract the number(s) from the summary entry at the top of the opencover (or reportgenerator) output and store that data somewhere useful then create your own graph.

As for your second issue the OpenCover documentation (a PDF/RTF that should have been installed alongside OpenCover, nuget and msi) details a switch that should do what you want.

```
-returntargetcode[:<opencoverreturncodeoffset>]
```

Comment: I haven't written any plug-ins for Jenkins.  Is it fair to assume I would have to do so in order to leverage your work?

Comment: Yes or there is this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592274/transform-opencover-xml-output-to-ncover-xml - which could possibly be used to get you going